# Algorithm to make numbers from match sticks

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, puzzle

I made a program to solve [this problem](http://acm.uva.es/archive/nuevoportal/data/problem.php?p=4292) from the ACM.

> Matchsticks are ideal tools to represent numbers. A common way to represent the ten decimal digits with matchsticks is the following:
>
> This is identical to how numbers are displayed on an ordinary alarm clock. With a given number of matchsticks you can generate a wide range of numbers. We are wondering what the smallest and largest numbers are that can be created by using all your matchsticks.
>
> Input
>
> On the first line one positive number: the number of testcases, at most 100. After that per testcase:
>
> One line with an integer n (2 ≤ n ≤ 100): the number of matchsticks you have.
>   Output
>
> Per testcase:
>
> One line with the smallest and largest numbers you can create, separated by a single space. Both numbers should be positive and contain no leading zeroes.
>   Sample Input
>
> 4
>   3
>   6
>   7
>   15
>   Sample Output
>
> 7 7
>   6 111
>   8 711
>   108 7111111

The problem is that it's way too slow to solve it for 100 matchsticks. The search tree is too big to bruteforce it.

Here are the results for the first 10:

2:  1 1

3:  7 7

4:  4 11

5:  2 71

6:  6 111

7:  8 711

8:  10 1111

9:  18 7111

10:  22 11111

The pattern for the maximums is easy but I don't see a shortcut for the minimums. Can someone suggest a better way to solve this problem? Here is the code I used:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    #define MAX 20 //should be 100

    //match[i] contains number of matches needed to form i
    int match[] = {6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6};
    string mi[MAX+1], ma[MAX+1];
    char curr[MAX+1] = "";

    //compare numbers saved as strings
    int mycmp(string s1, string s2)
    {
        int n = (int)s1.length();
        int m = (int)s2.length();
        if (n != m)
            return n - m;
        else
            return s1.compare(s2);
    }

    //i is the current digit, used are the number of matchsticks so far
    void fill(int i, int used)
    {
        //check for smaller and bigger values
        if (mycmp(curr, mi[used]) < 0) mi[used] = curr;
        if (mycmp(curr, ma[used]) > 0) ma[used] = curr;

        //recurse further, don't start numbers with a zero
        for (int a = i ? '0' : '1'; a <= '9'; a++) {
            int next = used + match[a-'0'];
            if (next <= MAX) {
                curr[i] = a;
                curr[i+1] = '\0';
                fill(i + 1, next);
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        //initialise 
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
            mi[i] = string(MAX, '9');
            ma[i] = "0";
        }

        //precalculate the values
        fill(0, 0);

        int n;
        cin >> n;

        //print those that were asked
        while (n--) {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            cout << mi[num] << " " << ma[num] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**EDIT** : I ended up using the dynamic programming solution. I tried it with dp before but I was messing around with a two-dimensional state array. The solutions here are much better. Thanks!

Comment: That's the problem with recursion. While I am not very sure if it applies to your problem but have you heard of "dynamic programming?" Most of the programming competition questions actually require a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: The result can be obtained in linear complexity. See my answer.

Comment: This question is now useless because the offsite link is now dead. This just goes to show why you shouldn't link to offsite questions without summarising them in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the result :

- first find the minimal number of digits for smallest number
- then proceed from most significant digit to the least significant one.

Every digit should be chosen so that there exists a solution for remaining digits.
Each digit requires between 2 and 7 matches. So you must choose the smallest Nth "top" digit that leaves the number of remaining matches between 2*(N-1) and 7*(N-1).

Do not forget that 0 has to be excluded from the search for the most significant digit of the result.

As a sidenote, one reason which makes this algorithm work is the fact that there is at least one corresponding digit for every value (of matches) between 2 and 7.

**EDIT :** example for 10 matches
10 matches --> 2 digits
Acceptable number of matches for top digit = between 3 and 7.
Smallest digit which requires between 3 and 7 matches -> 2 (which takes 5 matches), 0 being excluded.
Chosen first digit = 2

5 remaining matches  -->
Acceptable number of matches for second (and in this case last) digit = exactly 5
Smallest digit which requires 5 matches -> 2
Chosen second digit = 2

Result = 22.

**EDIT** code for this problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> nbMatchesForDigit;

long long minNumberForMatches(unsigned int nbMatches)
{
    int nbMaxMatchesForOneDigit = 7;
    int nbMinMatchesForOneDigit = 2;
    int remainingMatches = nbMatches;
    int nbDigits = 1 + nbMatches / nbMaxMatchesForOneDigit; 
    long long result = 0;
    for (int idDigit = 0 ; idDigit < nbDigits ; ++idDigit )
    {
        int minMatchesToUse = std::max(nbMinMatchesForOneDigit, remainingMatches - nbMaxMatchesForOneDigit * (nbDigits - 1 - idDigit));
        int maxMatchesToUse = std::min(nbMaxMatchesForOneDigit, remainingMatches - nbMinMatchesForOneDigit * (nbDigits - 1 - idDigit));
        for (int digit = idDigit > 0 ? 0 : 1 ; digit <= 9 ; ++digit )
        {
            if( nbMatchesForDigit[digit] >= minMatchesToUse && 
                nbMatchesForDigit[digit] <= maxMatchesToUse )
            {
                result = result * 10 + digit;
                remainingMatches -= nbMatchesForDigit[digit];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(6);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(2);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(5);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(5);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(4);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(5);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(6);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(3);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(7);
    nbMatchesForDigit.push_back(6);

    for( int i = 2 ; i <= 100 ; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << minNumberForMatches(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think a greedy algorithm will work in this case.  Pretty sure this is an example of a [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed from most significant digit to the least significant one"? How exactly do you fill them in? I think that's rather non-trivial.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then it doesn't work ; suppose you have ten matches. Your algorithm (it's a greedy one) will pick 8, then 7, returning 78. But with ten matches, 35 and 22 are better solutions.

Comment: I guess i haven't been clear describing my algorithm : see the example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dynamic programming solution.

Suppose that you have n matches, and you know how to solve the problem (minimum number) for all set of `n-k` matches, where `k` takes all the values corresponding to the number of matches that each number uses (2 for 1, 5 for 3, etc.)

The solution is then derived recursively. Supposing that you end your number with a one (in the least significant position), then the best solution is obtained by writing `(best solution with n-2 matches) 1`. Supposing you end it with a two, the best solution is `(best solution with n-5 matches) 2`. And so on ; eventually you can compare these ten numbers, and pick the best one.

So now, all you have to do is devise the best solution for all `n` smaller than your input, recursively.

**EDIT:** If you implement this algorithm in a straightforward way, you'll end up with an exponential complexity. The trick here is to notice that if your core function `MinimumGivenNMatches`, only takes one parameter, `n`. Hence you'll end up calling it with the same values a huge number of times.

To make the complexity linear, you just need to memoize (ie. remember) the solution for each `n`, using an auxiliary array.

Comment: Thanks! As an additional remark, the corresponding best solution can be found by keeping an additional array, `predecessor`; you just have to modify the main loop to keep track of the calls.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the dynamic programming method of remembering things is memoize as in memoization, not memorize. Good answer, though. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) instead of recursion.  It's significantly faster to store calculated values and re-use them. In fact, it turns an exponential running time into a polynomial one.

The basic idea is to have an array `min` which keeps track of the minimum number that can be made using exactly `n` matchsticks. So

```
min[0] = ""
min[1] = infinity
min[2] = "1"
min[3] = min("1+"min[3-2],"7")
min[4] = min("1"+min[4-2],"7"+min[4-3])
etc
```

Comment: The complexity of the optimal solution is linear. See my answer.

Comment: right, sorry. I am not sure how you would program this algorithm efficiently, though.

Comment: My solution is the same as Clément's. Basically just loop through values `0` to `N` of `min`, calculating each element. Then your answer is just `min[N]`.

Answer (score 1):

For the minima, note that because no leading zeros are allowed, you want to minimize the number of digits.  The minimal number of digits is `ceil(n/7)`.

Then it's quite easy to calculate the minimum number of matchsticks which MUST be used in the leading digit, from that you get the smallest possible value of the leading digit.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem with `O(d)`, where d is the number of digits. The idea is, first we calculate the minimum number of digits for the desired minimum number. This can be calculated by `int nofDigits = n/7+ ((0 == n%7) ? 0 : 1)`, where `n` is the number of matchsticks. Now create an array of `nofDigits`. Now we start filling maximum possible matchsticks (7) from least significant digit till one digit before max significant digit (MSD) and in the end assign all remaining matchsticks to the most significant digit (MSD). Now there are 3 possibilities of improvement depending on the number of matchsticks for MSD:

1st if the number of matchsticks for MSD is 1, then we can make it 2 by borrowing one matchstick from its adjacent digit. That will make the number of matchsticks for the adjacent digit 6, which is equivalent to 0

2d if the number of matchsticks for MSD is 4, then also same as previous case we can increment the number of matchsticks for MSD to 5, which is equivalent to 2

3rd if the number of matchsticks for MSD is 3, then we have to see if total number of digit is more than 2 then we can decrement 1 from two adjacent digits of MSD or else we will decrement one adjacent digit twice and increment number of matchsticks for MSD by 2

In the end by traversing through the array and replace number of matchsticks with the corresponding digit.

The complete program:

```
void minNumWithNMatches_no_dp (int n) {
    if (n < 2) return ;

    int digits[] = {-1, -1, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0, 8};

    int nofDigits = n/7+ ((0 == n%7) ? 0 : 1);

    int *matchesArr = new int [nofDigits];

    int tmp = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < nofDigits; ++i) {
        matchesArr[i] = tmp/7 ? 7 : tmp%7;
        tmp -= matchesArr[i];
    }

    if (nofDigits > 1)
    {
        switch (matchesArr[nofDigits - 1]) {
        case 1:
        case 4:
            {
                --matchesArr[nofDigits - 2];
                ++matchesArr[nofDigits - 1];
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                if (nofDigits > 2) {
                    --matchesArr[nofDigits - 2];
                    --matchesArr[nofDigits - 3];
                } else {
                    matchesArr[nofDigits - 2] -= 2;
                }
                matchesArr[nofDigits - 1] += 2;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        default:
            {
                ;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = nofDigits - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int digit = digits[matchesArr[i]];
        if ((i == nofDigits - 1) && (digit == 0)) digit = 6;
        std::cout<< digit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//  freopen("22.txt", "r", stdin);
    vector<char> count(10);
    map<int, char> Min_1;
    Min_1[0] = '8';
    Min_1[2] = '1';
    Min_1[3] = '7';
    Min_1[4] = '4';
    Min_1[5] = '2';
    count[0] = '6';
    count[1] = '2';
    count[2] = '5';
    count[3] = '5';
    count[4] = '4';
    count[5] = '5';
    count[6] = '6';
    count[7] = '3';
    count[8] = '7';
    count[9] = '6';
    int N = 99, P = 2;
    cin >> N;
    while(N --)
    {
        cin >> P;
        vector<char> min, max;
        int a = P, b = P;
        int total = (a + 6) / 7;
        int left = a % 7;
        bool first = true;
        char lastInsert = 0;
        while(a != 0)
        {
            if(total == 1)
            {
                if(left != 6)
                {
                    min.push_back(Min_1[left]);
                }else if(left == 6)
                {
                    if(!first)
                        min.push_back('0');
                    else
                        min.push_back('6');
                }
                break;
            }
            if(left == 0)
            {
                min.insert(min.end(), total, '8');
                break;
            }else{
                if(first && left <= 2)
                {
                    min.push_back('1');
                    lastInsert = 1;
                }else if(first && left < 6)
                {
                    min.push_back('2');
                    lastInsert = 2;
                }else if(first && left == 6)
                {
                    min.push_back('6');
                    lastInsert = 6;
                }else if(!first)
                {
                    min.push_back('0');
                    lastInsert = 0;
                } 
            }
            int temp = count[lastInsert] - '0';
            a -= temp;
            left = a % 7;
            total = (a + 6) / 7;
            first = false;
        }

        if(b % 2 == 1)
        {
            max.push_back('7');
            max.insert(max.end(), (b - 3) / 2, '1');
        }else{
            max.insert(max.end(), b / 2, '1');
        }
        string res_min = string(min.begin(), min.end());
        string res_max = string(max.begin(), max.end());
        cout << res_min << " " << res_max << endl;
        P ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my answer, wish it be helpful